# What are common approaches to build custom API connectors?

Tags: node.js, rest, express, heroku

I mostly have programming experience as a web developer, and now I'm tasked to build an integration between two rest services. The application is suppose to read from one REST service once every 5 minutes, and send the data to another service. I'll need to store a single checkSUM value somehow to be used on the next call.

At the moment I'm thinking about building it in Node and Express, hosted on heroku with a "Custom Clock Process". But I'm unsure what the best way to structure such an app is. It's quite foreign to me to work on an app without a view. Does MVC even make sense in such an app?

Can anyone point to resources explaining a good way to approach an app like this?

Does express make sense even without a view layer?

What is a good way to store a single value such as a checkSUM or SyncKey? 
Is a DB overkill?

What would the folder structure look like for an app like this.

I'm aware that this is pretty broad question. I'm mostly looking for suggestions and resources, and ideas on how other people would approach this. What tech would you use?

Comment: You don't have to use express for such a task, you can use single js file contains cron jobs to to get data from one service and send it to the other service. By the way, how many different endpoint you will request for first rest api ?  And is it because you use checkSUM to not send the same data to second rest service for the second time?

Comment: Im hitting 2 endpoints. And yes, the checksum is used to ensure the same data isn't being sent twice. The service that I'm reading from is providing it so that I can send that with the next request.

Comment: How would you trigger the cron?

Comment: There is [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) package in npm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) package to send request to your services. And [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) package to schedule your task for every 5 min.

Here is simple code for this scenario

```
var request = require('request');
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;

var SOURCE_SERVICE_URL = "http://your.source.service/endpoint";
var DESTINATION_SERVICE_URL =  "http://your.destination.service/endpoint";

//initialize this value when you get checkSUM from request and use to compare next checkSUM
var lastCheckSUM = "";

var everyMinuteJob = new CronJob({
    cronTime: '*/5 * * * *',
    onTick: function () {
        console.log("Task started");
        task_1();
        //you can create and add tasks for other endpoints
    },
    start: true
});


var task_1 = function () {
    request(SOURCE_SERVICE_URL, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Can not read data from source service.")
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log("Data read : " + body);
        //TODO - check the checkSUM value of response. Then set it to lastCheckSUM

        request
            .post(DESTINATION_SERVICE_URL, body, function (error, response, body) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log("Can not send data to destination service.")
                    return console.log(error);
                }
            })

    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense. Question: what happens to the checksum if the app crashes and restarts? Wouldn't it just be empty then? Potentially requesting data that has been transferred?

Comment: @MaltheMilthers you can store last checkSum value in a file, read it from that file at startup.

Comment: Thank you - this ended up being my solution .D